# How to UPDATE a user status in DB when datediff = 0

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a Users Table where i have one of the columns called ROLE. The values from select dropdown into the Role column is either "Pastor" Or "Usher" depending on the input by user at registration.

Their is also a column called EXPIRY-DATE, This column is filled by adding 90 days to the REG-DATE colunm.

See the Query that inserts into DB

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (titled, firstname, lastname, phone, email, 
            center_id, region_id, rolename, username, password, date, expirydate) 
        VALUES 
        ('$titled','$firstname','$lastname','$phone','$email','$center_name','$region_name ','$rolename','$username','$password', now(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 day))  ";

if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}else {
    $message = "Details submitted Successfully";
}
header("refresh:60 , url=register.php");
```

So at registration, The expirydate column is automatically filled with 90days future date of regdate.

On the Pastor's Account, is a countdown to expiration date. For example:  ***Your Subscription will expire in 24 day(s). Click here Click Here to extend it.*** kind of notification.

Now when this date difference counts down to 0 days(s), i want this notification message to change to completely to different message. For example: **Your Subscription has expired. Click here Click Here to renew.**

Unfortunately, my code is not changing this message.

Please help. I don't want JS please.

Code

```
<?php  

$expirydate = $_SESSION["expirydate"];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user_id, center_id, expirydate, 
        rolename FROM users WHERE rolename='Center Pastor' and user_id = '$user_id' 
        AND center_id = '$center_id'") or die("Failed".mysqli_error($con));

if ($result) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

        $current_date = date("Y-m-d");         
        $diff = (strtotime($expirydate) - strtotime($current_date));
        $total_days = floor ($diff / (60*60*24));

        echo ' will expire in '.$total_days.' day(s). Click here <a 
                        href="" class="alert-link">Click Here</a> to extend it.';
    }
    else {

        echo ' has expired. Click here <a href="" class="alert- 
                           link">Click Here</a> to renew.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$_SESSION['expirydate']`?

Comment: The query doesn't check the expiry date, so why would the number of rows have anything to do with whether the account has expired?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think what you are querying for too many columns, why don't you try selecting just the expiry date, as that is what u really need. So you can write your query like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT expirydate FROM users WHERE  and user_id = '$user_id'") or die("Failed".mysqli_error($con));
```

Secondly the message is not changing because your query is either failing or this line

```
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
```

is returning a value less than 0 or 0